# Real-time Percentage Calculator with two outputs

Tags: javascript, html

Good day!

I am trying to work on a Real-time Percentage Calculator that displays results upon user input using JavaScript onkeyup="calc();" and step up function attached to buttons. It works when i input text but does not work when i click the addition and subtraction keys side by side the input field.

Secondly i was hoping there could be a way to define two values for each drop down option and output each result of value percentage separately. Assuming <option value 1="22" value=2 "22" >22% & 6%

For the first question, here is my code.

```js
function calc() {
  var i = document.getElementById("amount_trade").value;
  var p = document.getElementById("percent").value;
  var o = (i / 100) * p;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = o;
}
```

```css
input[type="number"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
Input: <button type="button" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('#amount_trade').stepDown()" class="btn btn-primary default"><strong>-</i></strong></button>

<input type="number" id="amount_trade" onkeyup="calc();" onchange="calc();" />

<button type="button" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('#amount_trade').stepUp()" class="btn btn-primary default"><strong>+</button><br />

<select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" id="percent" onchange="calc();">
  <option value="50">50% &amp; 2%</option>
  <option value="22">22% &amp; 6%</option>
  <option value="16">16% &amp; 10%</option>
  <option value="8">8% &amp; 15%</option>
  <option value="4">4% &amp; 67%</option>
</select>


<span id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a delegated script using recommended event listeners instead of inline event handlers

I also fixed your invalid HTML in the buttons

I gave the options the values separated by semicolon to have two values in one option

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const amount = document.getElementById("amount_trade")
const percent = document.getElementById("percent");
const out1 = document.getElementById("out1");
const out2 = document.getElementById("out2");

// reusable function
const calc = function(e) {
  const amt = amount.value;
  const p = percent.value.split(";")
  const o1 = (amt / 100) * p[0];
  const o2 = (amt / 100) * p[1];
  out1.innerHTML = o1.toFixed(2);
  out2.innerHTML = o2.toFixed(2);
};

// any click in the container - it is called delegation
container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("btn")) { // use a more specific class if you will have more buttons
    if (tgt.id === "up") amount.stepUp(); // it is up
    else amount.stepDown(); // else it is down. Add an "if" if needed
  }
  calc(); // always calc
})

container.addEventListener("input", calc); // any input will calculate
```

```css
input[type="number"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  Input: <button type="button" id="down" class="btn btn-primary default">-</button>

  <input type="number" id="amount_trade" value="0" />

  <button type="button" id="up" class="btn btn-primary default">+</button><br />

  <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" id="percent">
    <option value="50;2">50% &amp; 2%</option>
    <option value="22;6">22% &amp; 6%</option>
    <option value="16;10">16% &amp; 10%</option>
    <option value="8;15">8% &amp; 15%</option>
    <option value="4;67">4% &amp; 67%</option>
  </select>


  <span id="out1"></span> - <span id="out2"></span>
</div>
```

You could also have ONE output div and then

```
output.innerHTML = `<span id="out1">${o1.toFixed(2)}</span>  
                    <span id="out2">${o2.toFixed(2)}</span>`;
```

Comment: Please help further with this. I want to display output with two different spans, e.g <span id="output1"></span>  <span id="output2"></span>

Comment: If you do understand my question Please do update the code and point me correctly!

Comment: You could also have done `output.innerHTML = \`<span id="out1">${o1.toFixed(2)}</span> - <span id="out2">${o2.toFixed(2)}</span>\`;`

Answer (score 0):

You can add `calc()` function to button `onclick`

```js
function calc() {
  var i = document.getElementById("amount_trade").value;
  var p = document.getElementById("percent").value;
  var o = (i / 100) * p;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = o;
}
```

```css
input[type="number"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
Input: <button type="button" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('#amount_trade').stepDown();calc();" class="btn btn-primary default"><strong>-</i></strong></button>

<input type="number" id="amount_trade" onkeyup="calc();" onchange="calc();" />

<button type="button" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('#amount_trade').stepUp();calc();" class="btn btn-primary default"><strong>+</button><br />

<select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" id="percent" onchange="calc();">
  <option value="50">50% &amp; 2%</option>
  <option value="22">22% &amp; 6%</option>
  <option value="16">16% &amp; 10%</option>
  <option value="8">8% &amp; 15%</option>
  <option value="4">4% &amp; 67%</option>
</select>


<span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: It worked Perfectly! Thanks a bunch... How about The second question?  i was hoping there could be a way to define two values for each drop down option and output each result of value percentage separately. Assuming <option value 1="22" value=2 "22" >22% & 6%</option>

Comment: Look for @mplungjan's answer

Answer (score 0):

You want this ?

```js
function calc() {
  var i = document.getElementById("amount_trade").value;
  var p = document.getElementById("percent").value;
  var o = (i / 100) * p;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = o;
}

function plus () { 
document.getElementById("amount_trade").stepUp();
  calc();
}

function minus () { 
document.getElementById("amount_trade").stepDown() ;
  calc()
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="minus()" class="btn btn-primary default"><strong>-</i></strong></button>

<input type="number" id="amount_trade" onkeyup="calc();" onchange="calc();" />

<button type="button" onclick="plus()" class="btn btn-primary default"><strong>+</button><br />

<select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" id="percent" onchange="calc();">
  <option value="50">50% &amp; 2%</option>
  <option value="22">22% &amp; 6%</option>
  <option value="16">16% &amp; 10%</option>
  <option value="8">8% &amp; 15%</option>
  <option value="4">4% &amp; 67%</option>
</select>


<span id="output"></span>
```